# How to sort directory by last modified content?

Tags: unix, centos7, ls

I believe directories should be, by default, sorted by last modified content with `ls -lt`. But it turns out not to be the case, at least in my CentOS 7 system. Please see the terminal output below.

It seems like the directories are sorted as expected when files are CREATED, but not when they are MODIFIED.

How could I have them sorted by the last modification time of anything inside it?

```
[chinazzo@potzblix test]$ mkdir dir1
[chinazzo@potzblix test]$ mkdir dir2
[chinazzo@potzblix test]$ echo "Create in dir1" > dir1/file
[chinazzo@potzblix test]$ ls -lta
total 4
drwxrwxr-x.  2 chinazzo chinazzo   18 Jan 19 11:55 dir1     # Ok
drwxrwxr-x.  4 chinazzo chinazzo   30 Jan 19 11:55 .
drwxrwxr-x.  2 chinazzo chinazzo    6 Jan 19 11:55 dir2
drwx------. 31 chinazzo chinazzo 4096 Jan 19 11:49 ..
[chinazzo@potzblix test]$ echo "Create in dir2" > dir2/file
[chinazzo@potzblix test]$ ls -lta
total 4
drwxrwxr-x.  2 chinazzo chinazzo   18 Jan 19 11:56 dir2     # Ok
drwxrwxr-x.  2 chinazzo chinazzo   18 Jan 19 11:55 dir1
drwxrwxr-x.  4 chinazzo chinazzo   30 Jan 19 11:55 .
drwx------. 31 chinazzo chinazzo 4096 Jan 19 11:49 ..
[chinazzo@potzblix test]$ echo "Mod in dir1" >> dir1/file
[chinazzo@potzblix test]$ ls -lta
total 4
drwxrwxr-x.  2 chinazzo chinazzo   18 Jan 19 11:56 dir2
drwxrwxr-x.  2 chinazzo chinazzo   18 Jan 19 11:55 dir1     # Not ok, notice mtime 11:55
drwxrwxr-x.  4 chinazzo chinazzo   30 Jan 19 11:55 .
drwx------. 31 chinazzo chinazzo 4096 Jan 19 11:49 ..
[chinazzo@potzblix test]$ ls -lta dir1
total 4
-rw-rw-r--. 1 chinazzo chinazzo 27 Jan 19 11:56 file        # but file (in dir1) mtime 11:56
drwxrwxr-x. 2 chinazzo chinazzo 18 Jan 19 11:55 .
drwxrwxr-x. 4 chinazzo chinazzo 30 Jan 19 11:55 ..
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use find:

```
find . -type d -printf "%Ts/%f\n" | sort -n
```

Search for only directories and then print the last modification time in epoch format (%Ts) as well as the directory name (%f). Pipe the output to sort -n to order the directories by modification time.

Comment: Thanks. Added `-maxdepth 1` to have the same behavior as `ls` and `sort -nr` to have the last modified in the top: `find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -printf "%Ts/%f\n" | sort -nr`